# Split long strings without spaces to multiple lines at a given length in a text file

Tags: string, vim, text

I have a text file containing some very long lines with no spaces. 
These lines contain no whitespace or other common delimiters.
I would like to split these long lines into seperate lines so that no line in the text file is longer than 80 characters. Is this possible inside vim or perhaps using some other tool?

Comment: For a quick and dirty solution in vim, you can just record a macro that goes right 80 times, inserts a linebreak, goes to the next line and then repeat that macro n times until you've reached the end of your file.

Comment: Clever, I will give that a try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick vim solution:

assume we have a long line of text:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

that we want to split into pieces of 10:

```
gg (for first line), 
q[letter] (for recording a macro), 
10l (for going right n times), 
a return ESC (for entering a linebreak after current character and leaving insert mode), 
q (to stop recording).
```

We should now be on line 2 with our cursor, looking like this:

```
aaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

A quick `100@[letter]` formats the entire line:

```
aaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaa
```

Comment: Thank you man. I never had the desire to use macros in vim and I feel rather stupid to not have looked into it sooner.

Comment: @lsund This video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SkdrYWhh-8s is a great summary for everything I'd have to say about vim. And it's a fantastic video apart from that as well.